# Related/Linked question vote counts for same question differ -- caching?

Tags: bug, related-questions, linked-questions

This is probably caching. (It's always caching.) But just in case something is genuinely awry, I present this bizarre screenshot, taken a bare few minutes ago:
[image]
There you have it.

Comment: Although it's an old question it looks like it very recently got two upvotes because of a related meta post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283431/an-incorrect-answer-upvoted-and-accepted

Comment: @PeterJ: And here I was thinking the upvotes were from the question I was working on ... ;)